# how to trigger jQuery $.post

Tags: php, jquery, post, triggers

I want to send data to a php file when I click a link

```
<a href="test.html" onclick ="post()">click me</a>
```

I have in an external JS file

```
function post(){
   $.post("myPhp.php", { name: "John" });
}
```

but when I check my PHP file, nothing gets posted.

`$_POST['name']` is undefined.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you check if your post function gets called ?

Comment: when you click on that link it will be redirected to the corresponding page before your ajax is completed.So try to stop that redirection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this,Reason your code was not working because before your ajax request is submited ,your page get redirected

```
   <a href="test.html" onclick ="return post()">click me</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
function post(){
   $.post("myPhp.php", { name: "John" });
   return false;
}
```

**EDITED CODE**

To redirect page use async

```
    function post(){
       $.ajax({url:"myPhp.php", 
              data: {name: "John"},
              type:'post',
              async: false,
              success: function(data){
                return true;    
              },
         });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! this actually worked, but I want it to redirect after. Any advice?

Comment: @DeepakManwal sure its going to redirect

Comment: I have made little change this can be using $.post.

Answer (score 1):

I think its redirected to the corresponding page before your ajax is completed.So try to stop that redirection with following code like:

```
<a href="javscript:void(0)" onclick ="post()">click me</a>

function post(){
   $.post("myPhp.php", { name: "John" },function(){
    window.location.href('test.html');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think the error is with the name ... it should be some string.

```
var name = 'name';

or 

data: {'name' : 'john'}
```

Hope this helps. Also try adding callbacks to check if your post data is sent successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same problem you had. 
If you are using **jquery.redirect.min.js** as your jquery plugin, You can use as below. It gives you POST method.

```
   $().redirect("myPhp.php", { name: "John" });
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: I'm using the entire jquery library actually

Answer (score -1):

try the follwing

```
function post(){
   $.ajax({url:"myPhp.php", 
          data: {name: "John"},
          type:'post',
          success: funcation(data){},
          });
}
```

or find a quick overview of $.post here and then use it properly http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @Ankush - what you have done should be done as $.ajax() if i am not wrong? is this is the syntax of $.post()!

Comment: I think you you are suggesting is to do same thing